# Keyboard notifications and presentModalViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I get twice notification on keyboard down and once on keyboard up…

In my class I put notifications for keyboard:

```
-(id)init… {
…
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
…
}
```

to do frame adjustment on keyboard slide.

Later during the class work I use `'ABPeoplePickerNavigationController'` to select address.

```
…
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *userPicker=[[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
…
[viewController presentModalViewController:userPicker animated:YES];
…
```

I’ve found that on `‘presentModalViewController’` I get twice `‘UIKeyboardWillHideNotification’` , BUT once  `‘UIKeyboardWillShowNotification’` – when the picker goes out.

Pretty strange.

I tried to remove observer for `‘UIKeyboardWillHideNotification’` from the class initialization (to find any double observer declarations). However, after this remove no `‘UIKeyboardWillHideNotification’` notifications at all.

Why I get different amount of notifications on keyboard up and down?

May be I do something wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite common (especially with the *WillDoSomething message) to receive a notification twice though you expected just once. 
What you could do to fix the problem is to have a boolean somewhere which stores the state of the UI. For instance, if keyboardUp is false would mean that you already move the UI to the default state.